# One Signal Android Handle Silent Notification

Tags: android, xamarin.android, onesignal

How I can push a silent Notification to android Application and handle it on app and show new message to user when appllication is Killed,Stopped

for example I have a message to user let's say : "Hello How Are you"
is there any way to do some functionality for this notification before show it to user for example replace the previous message with "Hello Tom How Are you "

and save it in sqllite db when the application closed not running

Answer (score 2):

You can handle silent notification in android native application example below code

```
public class OneSignalSilentNotificationHandler extends NotificationExtenderService {

    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
        // if you want silent notification then return true else false
    //Change title and body according to your requirements
    receivedResult.payload.title = "title";
    receivedResult.payload.body = "body";
    JSONObject
        return false;
    }
```

in AndroidManifest.xml put code snippets

```
<service
        android:name=".util.OneSignalSilentNotificationHandler"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Here's Onesignal docs link
[Onesignal notification docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding)